# How can I write an automated code to copy the table from this website?

Tags: java, url

I would like to copy the table from this website =

http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tlt/dividend-history

everytime I open my jar file and paste it into a csv file.  I already know how to download a csv file from websites that provide a download button for it.  But now I need to copy it from this URL, which doesn't provide a download button.  Please help?!

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? I thought I am asking a reasonable question?...

Comment: You have not shown any effort. The question is too broad and doesnt focus on problem.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you did not show any effort. Questions "how can I do" can be consider either too broad or off-topic. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answers.  I really do not know where to start because I had searched all over the internet but came up with very random answers that doesn't seem to pin-point what I am looking for.  I just wanted a very basic explanation on how to do it, not someone to write a code for me.  Example: do I have to use a scanner on the website's code and look for a specific character then copy every data after that or...

Comment: you can use jsoup it seems .

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh Thanks for the reply, I googled it and it seem to be closer to what I am looking for but I am still lost.  I had just started out programming around a week ago and need someone to guide me through this.  Can I open a chat window on stackoverflow with you so you can help guide me through this?  It wouldn't take long.  And if yes, how can I open a chat window with you? O.O

Comment: @ChoongJing provided some hints to your questions, Explore futher with jsoup library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, it will give you the required data.

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tlt/dividend-history").get();
    Element content = document.select("#quotes_content_left_ContentPanel").first();
    System.out.println(content.html());
```

**Basic functionality:**

- Fire the URL and read the data from it.
- Now as the required data resides between which tag you have to figure out that. Here, [image] the highlighted part is the required data.
- Now you have to refer the JSOUP documents more to get used to the libraries and functionlity provided.
- I have extracted the data on the basis of the `"id"` of the html element. Similarly there are many functionality you should checkout.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!  The effort you put into helping others is admirable!

Comment: @ChoongJing mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with HTML tables is that they often vary in their HTML-design and if you learn how to deal with this one, the next one may provide problems. [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) can help you in general and with this problem specifically, but you will need to look at the source code of the site in question (your browser can you help do that, if in doubt use its help function to search for the functionality) to extract the information needed with JSoup.

**EDIT:** based on your comment, learn about HTML first before you automatically want to download tables. Your problem may be a bit too advanced if you just started out. I also doubt you will find tutors on this site, that's not what it is for.

Comment: I am very new to programming and before this I never knew that programming can be this complex.  I just opened the developer tool for this website and opened the source code for "how-can-i-write....-this-website".   Let's say I want to copy the line you just wrote "The problems with HTML.... needed with JSoup" and paste it into a txt file.  How can I do that on Netbeans Java.

Comment: Thank You for your kind tone.  I marked your answer as the correct one.